# Get HTML string from URL

Tags: php, html, arrays, url

here is my code to send an email:

```
$result = $client->sendEmail([
    'Message' => [
        'Body' => [
            'Html' => [
                'Data' => '<string>', // PUT HTML FILE HERE
            ],
            'Text' => [
                'Data' => '<string>',
            ],
        ]
    ]
]);
```

I have a `template.php` file which is the email template. i don't want to paste it in the html data because it is too long and it looks unorganized. how can i get the contents of `http://www.example.com/template.php` in the `Html` `Data` field using a link or url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get contents of http://www.example.com/template.php by file_get_contents

```
$result = $client->sendEmail([
    'Message' => [
        'Body' => [
            'Html' => [
                'Data' => file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/template.php'),
            ],
            'Text' => [
                'Data' => '<string>',
            ],
        ]
    ]
]);
```